# What exactly is ReAuth?

Tags: login, authentication

Searching for "**WordPress Reauth**" and the like all result in folks who are having problems with `ReAuth=1`. What exactly is ReAuth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ReAuth=1` is required when your login `Cookies` are no longer valid, WordPress will force validation for your browser.

```
if ( $force_reauth ) 
    $login_url = add_query_arg('reauth', '1', $login_url);
```

> - Add reauth=1 flag to login url when auth_redirect() redirects to    wp-login.php after the auth cookie fails validation wp-login.php
>     clears cookies and forces log in if reauth=1.
> - If reauth=1 wp-login.php does not attempt to redirect to wp-admin,    even if the cookie seems good.
>
> Basically, this forces reauth/login whenever auth_redirect() does not
>   think the user is logged in. This should resolve the situation where
>   one cookie seems good but another does not.

--- Ryan via [Trac 12142](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12142)

To fix issues with this you can clear your cookies and change your Security Keys, or use `wp_set_auth_cookie`.

Some reference:
http://digwp.com/2010/09/wordpress-security-keys/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie

Comment: Excellent! That would make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Wyck - THANK YOU for the best answer I've read regarding this issue! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Thanks for the info! just call [`wp_clear_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_clear_auth_cookie/) if anybody making a custom login and had a `GET` reauth.